# How to define the type signature on this Affjax call

Tags: types, purescript

I am having this simple program using Affjax and `launchAff`.

```
import Network.HTTP.Affjax as Affjax
import Control.Monad.Aff (launchAff)

test1 = launchAff $ do Affjax.get "/api"
```

this gives me the following error

```
 58  test1 = launchAff $ do Affjax.get "/api"
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

 No type class instance was found for

 Network.HTTP.Affjax.Response.Respondable _0

 The instance head contains unknown type variables. Consider adding a type annotation.

 in value declaration test1

 where _0 is an unknown type
```

I understand that `Respondable` needs to be be defined here but I really dont get how to do it exactly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to annotate your test1 function to let the compiler know what you expect to get back from that ajax call.

```
test1 = launchAff do
  Affjax.get "/api" :: Affjax _ Foreign
```

You can choose any one of [these instances](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-affjax/blob/620009b54bfc0e58617c737716693fffd784ec72/src/Network/HTTP/Affjax/Response.purs#L61-L91) for your return type, or if you expect your own datatype to be returned, write a `Respondable` instance for it.

EDIT: I edited the source code. The provided codesnippet isn't very useful though, since you're not doing anything with the AJAX response. Since `Affjax` operates inside `Aff` you can use do notation to bind the result of the `GET` call to a variable and proceed to use it from there.